# A function working in a custom file but not in a "custom migration" on Django

Tags: python, django, orm, migration

I am beginner in Django and just started learning migrations. In a DB table, I am trying to remove a row that has a specific field value. When I create a custom file which uses Django settings, the function properly deletes the row. But when I use the snippet in another function in a custom migration file, the deletion doesn't take place.

It is possible that I am missing something elementary as a beginner.

So I am trying to delete all orders the status of which is cancelled.
The function that works in a separate file is:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "orm_skeleton.settings")
django.setup()

from main_app.models import Order

def delete_test_fnc():
    all_orders = Order.objects.all()

    for i in range(len(all_orders) - 1, -1, -1):
        order = all_orders[i]
        if order.status == "Cancelled":
            order.delete()

delete_test_fnc()
```

The custom migration where delete doesnt work (other two modifications work without issues) is:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.db import migrations

CURRENT_ORDERS = []

def modify_delivery_warranty(apps, schema_editor):
    global CURRENT_ORDERS
    orders = apps.get_model("main_app", "Order")

    all_orders = orders.objects.all()
    CURRENT_ORDERS = all_orders

    for i in range(len(all_orders) - 1, -1, -1):
        order = all_orders[i]
        if order.status == "Cancelled":
            order.delete()
        elif order.status == "Pending":
            order.delivery = order.order_date + timedelta(days=3)
        elif order.status == "Completed":
            order.warranty = "24 months"
        order.save()


def revert_modify_delivery_warranty(apps, schema_editor):
    orders = apps.get_model("main_app", "Order")
    orders.objects.all().delete()

    for order in CURRENT_ORDERS:
        new_order = orders.objects.create(
            product_name=order.get("product_name"),
            customer_name=order.get("customer_name"),
            order_date=order.get("order_date"),
            amount=order.get("amount"),
            product_price=order.get("product_price"),
            total_price=order.get("total_price"),
            warranty=order.get("warranty"),
            delivery=order.get("delivery")
        )
        new_order.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main_app', '0021_order'),`your text`
    ]

    operations = [migrations.RunPython(
        modify_delivery_warranty, 
        reverse_code=revert_modify_delivery_warranty
    )
    ]
```

Comment: Sorry to be 'that guy' that doesn't answer your question but do you really need to be deleting these cancelled rows? It's often useful to keep track of 'cancelled' data. Instead of deleting these rows, another option would be to filter on only rows that are _not_ cancelled when getting data from this table. That way cancelled orders will not appear in the application where the filter is applied, and you still have a record of these orders which were cancelled which could be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that if the status is `Cancelled`, you call `order.delete()` which deletes it from the database. But the Python object itself is still in the memory in variable `order`.. After all if statements, you call `order.save()` which saves the object back to database. Which means your object is indeed deleted but it is saved again.

So, a way to fix it is by calling `order.save()` only when needed:

```
for i in range(len(all_orders) - 1, -1, -1):
    order = all_orders[i]
    if order.status == "Cancelled":
        order.delete()
    if order.status == "Pending":
        order.delivery = order.order_date + timedelta(days=3)
    elif order.status == "Completed":
        order.warranty = "24 months"

    if order.status != "Cancelled":
        order.save()
```

Another important note is that the code you implemented will *not* revert back the deleted objects because once you run `python manage.py migrate` and it stops, all in-memory objects are deleted after the process exists. Which means when you try to revert the migration, the `CURRENT_ORDERS` will be empty. For more about this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/